# Fetching data from Oracle to query Table

Tags: sql, oracle, fetch

I am trying to fetch a query to extract data from an Oracle Database, but get an error message when trying to produce the final data frame to work on.

## packages already installed

```
library(ROracle)
library(RODBC)
```

### create the connection to the database

```
con<-dbConnect(Oracle(), username='xxxx', password='xxxx', dbname='xxxx')
```

### query the data

```
query<- dbSendQuery(con,"select * from table")
```

### execute query and return results in object of type dataframe

```
result<- fetch(query)
```

Everything works fine till the last line, where I want to fetch the query:

Error message is:

> Error in .valueClassTest(ans, "data.frame", "fetch") : invalid value
>   from generic function ‘fetch’, class “try-error”, expected
>   “data.frame”

I couldn't find any proper explanation for solving this problem. Any idea ?

Comment: What types of fields do you have in your table? Are there any LOB fields? Can you try selecting only required fields instead of using *?

Comment: Selecting specific fields only in the SQL statement instead of * works fine. Many thanks for your useful help!!

Comment: You're welcome. If the problem is with LOBS - you can use the dbms_lob package to extract text from the LOB-fields that you need.

Comment: is dbms_lob a package in R? I couldn't find anything using google search. I just found references to Oracle. Any resources you can share? I want to query the column with the LOB. Thanks