# R-SQL Invalid value from generic function ‘fetch’, class “try-error”, expected “data.frame”

Tags: sql, r, oracle

I am having a problem to fetch some data from database using ROracle. Everything works perfect (I am getting the data from different tables without any problem), but one of the tables throws an error:

```
 library(ROracle)
    con <- dbConnect(dbDriver("Oracle"),"xxx/x",username="user",password="pwd")
    spalten<- dbListFields(con, name="xyz", schema = "x") # i still get the name of the columns for this table
    rs <- dbSendQuery(con, "Select * From x.xyz") # no error
    data <- fetch(rs) # this line throws an error
    dbDisconnect(con)
```

> Fehler in .valueClassTest(ans, "data.frame", "fetch") :    invalid
>   value from generic function ‘fetch’, class “try-error”, expected
>   “data.frame”

I followed this question: [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34762144/fetching-data-from-oracle-to-query-table), and i selected the columns

```
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, "Select a From x.xyz")
```

but none of it worked and gave me the same error.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

P.S. I have checked the sql query in Oracle SQL Developer, and I do get the data table there

**Update:**

If anyone can help me to locate/query my Oracle error log, then perhaps I can find out what is actually happening on the database server with my troublesome query.

Comment: Is there any output in the Oracle error logs?  What is the exact line which fails?  Can you call `dbSendQuery(...)` without an assignment, without any error?

Comment: the line which throws an error is `data <- fetch(rs)`, calling `dbSendQuery(...)` comes without any error

Comment: I suspect that there is a problem with your database connection.  What do you see when you type `con` in the R console _after_ attempting to connect?  Are there any fields which indicate whether or not the connection were made successfully?

Comment: The connection is succesfull, and i am sure about it, i tried getting some other tables, and i fetched the data without any problem, thats whats wondering me...only this one table throws an error

Comment: Can you show us code for a query where you _were_ able to get a result set?

Answer (score 0):

This is for debugging purposes only.  Try running your code in the following `tryCatch` construct.  It will display all warnings and errors which are happening.

```
result <- tryCatch({
    con <- dbConnect(dbDriver("Oracle"),"xxx/x",username="user",password="pwd")
    spalten <- dbListFields(con, name="xyz", schema = "x")
    rs <- dbSendQuery(con, "Select * From x.xyz") # no error
    data <- fetch(rs) # this line throws an error
    dbDisconnect(con) 
}, warning = function(war) {
    print(paste("warning:  ",war))
}, error = function(err) {
    print(paste("error:  ",err))
})

print(paste("result =",result))
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks soo much!Error seems the same 
`[1] "error:   Error in .valueClassTest(ans, \"data.frame\", structure(\"fetch\", package = \"DBI\")): invalid value from generic function ‘fetch’, class “try-error”, expected “data.frame”\n"
> print(paste("result =",result))
[1] "result = error:   Error in .valueClassTest(ans, \"data.frame\", structure(\"fetch\", package = \"DBI\")): invalid value from generic function ‘fetch’, class “try-error”, expected “data.frame”\n"`

Comment: Can you query any other table in the `x` schema?  Is there anything special about table `xyz` (or whatever the real names are) ?

Comment: The query is causing an error, but the R API expects a data frame to come back.  You need to figure out what about the query is wrong.

Comment: I can query any other table in this schema, and actually there is nothing special in `xyz` table, 7 columns which seem to be normal, and even trying to get only one of the column (which is plain numeric) throws an error

Comment: Are you certain that the Oracle logs have no information about this?  The database must be throwing some error.

Comment: Hmm the same sql query works in Oracle SQL Developer.. it actually does not throw any error, thats the strangest thing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103928/discussion-between-tim-biegeleisen-and-malvina-a).

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the game on this question, but I had a similar issue and discovered the problem: My query also ran fine in SQL Developer, but that only fetches 50 rows at a time. ROracle fetches the whole data set. So, an issue that appears later in the data set won't show immediately in SQL Developer. Once I pages through results in SQL Developer, it threw and error at a certain point because there was a problem with the actual value stored in the table. Not sure how an invalid value got there, but fixing it fixed the problem in ROracle.